# Debezium or JDBC skip tables without primary key

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, primary-key, debezium

I have Debezium in a container, capturing all changes of PostgeSQL database records. In addition a have a confluent JDBC container to write all changes to another database.

In the source connector the definition is allowing multiple tables to be captured and therefore some of the tables have primary keys and some others not.

In the sink connector the definition specifies pk.mode like the following:

```
"insert.mode": "upsert",
"delete.enabled": "true",
"pk.mode": "record_key",
```

But while there are tables in the source database without keys on the tables, sink connector is throwing the following message:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: PK mode for table 'contex_str_dealer_branch_address' is RECORD_KEY, but record key schema is missing
```

Normally there should be a few options

1. to exclude tables without primary keys from the source
2. to exclude tables without primary keys from the sink
3. to have primary key for tables that they have or use all other columns for tables that they have not primary key

Is there any way to skip those tables from any operation?

Answer (score 0):

In debezium there isn't a parameter to filter tables without primary keys.

If you know the table in advance you can use `database.exclude.list` in debeziun connector source.

In the JDBC sink connector you have two options:

Ignored as no fields are used as primary key.

```
 "pk.mode": "none"
```

Or all fields from the value struct will be used

```
 "pk.mode": "record_value"
```

Comment: sure there is always the option to exclude those tables, but i am looking a more automated approach to this issue.